# Visual Studio 2010 - Tools.Settings menu missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am running VS 2010 Ultimate and have recently switched from C# to C++ & assembler but I am unable to view the registers or memory windows because I am unable to check the **Expert Settings**. This is because my Tools menu, the traditional route of access, has no **Settings** option. Instead, there is an **Import and Export Settings** option. This is normally a sub-menu of **Tools.Settings**. Has anybody had the same experience and solved it or does anobody know of an alternative to accessing **Expert Settings**?

TIA

Comment: It's Tools/Options not Tools/Settings. I do not have any Tools/Settings.

Comment: Although viewing Memory or Registers are on the Debug/Windows menu.

Comment: @ drescherjm Well you know more than VS2010 help. Perhaps you would be kind enough to delve further to find the expert settings. I have and failed to find any reference to Expert Settings in Tools/Options, even in the Debugging section.

Comment: @ drescherjm Alas Memory or Registers are not on the Debug/Windows menu until after Expert Settings is checked. Hence my question.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 Pro. I have installed it many times here at work over the years and with the default options these options are enabled by default. I am confused how this is not so in Ultimate. User rights/ UAC?

Comment: @ drescherjm I have no recollection of have made changes that might, now, be denying me access to the Expert Settings that all my research suggests are essential to getting access to the Registers or Memory  windows (though it might be that this requirement is only applicable to C++ 2010 express([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384844(v=vs.100).aspx) my version of Help Library Agent makes no mention of that, though). I have been using VS2010 for over 3 years (though only for C#), so it is possible. However, thank you for your kind attention.